# How do I add points to 3d surface plot in r?

Tags: r, plot, 3d, surface

I'm creating a surface plot in r however have not quite secured the correct code as this is my first meddle with 3d plots. In this case my response variable y is lnf_t and my two predictor variables are temp (x1) and sm_t (x2) (the data are copied at the end, values have been slightly adjusted from the original). Firstly I am attempting to overlay the data points onto the graph itself and secondly I would like the axes to show the range of the data rather than the number of observations in the dataset. I have attempted to adjust the codes from other questions in the forum without success although they have got me this far! This is what I have:

```
y<-lnf_t
x1<-temp
x2<-sm_t

mod1 = loess(y~x1*x2, data=dat, degree=2, span = 0.25)
fit = expand.grid(x1=seq(range(x1)[1],range(x1)[2],length=180), 
                  x2=seq(range(x2)[1],range(x2)[2],length=180))
z = predict(mod1, newdata = fit)
fit$Height = as.numeric(z)
persp(seq(x1),seq(x2),z,phi=30,theta=30,
      xlab = "T", ylab = "SM", zlab = "ln C", main = "lnF",
      ticktype="detailed", shade = .75, border = NA)
```

[Current plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eiJUr.png)

Here is one of my attempts at adding points (adapted from a similar question in this forum):

```
depth3d <- function(x1,x2,y, pmat, minsize=0.2, maxsize=2) {
tr <- as.matrix(cbind(x1, x2, y, 1)) %*% pmat
tr <- tr[,3]/tr[,4]
psize <- ((tr-min(tr) ) * (maxsize-minsize)) / (max(tr)-min(tr)) + minsize
return(psize)
}
psize = depth3d(x1,x2,y,pmat,minsize=0.1, maxsize = 1)
mypoints <- trans3d(x1, x2, y, pmat=pmat)
points(mypoints, pch=8, cex=psize, col=4)
```

The main issue seems to be in the pmat part of the code although I am not familiar with several of the functions here. the majority of the code runs fine until the error as follows:

```
depth3d <- function(x1,x2,y, pmat, minsize=0.2, maxsize=2) {
+ tr <- as.matrix(cbind(x1, x2, y, 1)) %*% pmat
+ tr <- tr[,3]/tr[,4]
+ psize <- ((tr-min(tr) ) * (maxsize-minsize)) / (max(tr)-min(tr)) + minsize
+ return(psize)
+ }
> psize = depth3d(x1,x2,y,pmat,minsize=0.1, maxsize = 1)
Error in depth3d(x1, x2, y, pmat, minsize = 0.1, maxsize = 1) : 
  object 'pmat' not found
> mypoints <- trans3d(x1, x2, y, pmat=pmat)
Error in trans3d(x1, x2, y, pmat = pmat) : object 'pmat' not found
> points(mypoints, pch=8, cex=psize, col=4)
Error in points(mypoints, pch = 8, cex = psize, col = 4) : 
  object 'mypoints' not found
```

1) I am trying to add the data points themselves onto the plot.

2)  The range for T (x1) should be the actual data values, i.e; 5, 14.5 and 23, not 0-180 (the number of observations in my dataset). Likewise the range for SM (x2) should be the range of the data not the number of observations.

I'm running r Version 0.99.902 on a Mac

Hope that all makes sense, any help would be very much appreciated! Since I'm still learning to talk R some explanation of the code would be great too.

Thanks!
Quinn

```
dat <- structure(list(temp = c(5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
5, 5, 14.5, 14.5, 14.5, 14.5, 14.5, 14.5, 14.5, 5, 23, 23, 23, 
23, 23, 23, 23, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
14.5, 14.5, 14.5, 14.5, 14.5, 14.5, 14.5, 5, 23, 23, 23, 23, 
23, 23, 23, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 14.5, 
14.5, 14.5, 14.5, 14.5, 14.5, 14.5, 5, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 
23, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 14.5, 14.5, 
14.5, 14.5, 14.5, 14.5, 14.5, 5, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 
5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 14.5, 14.5, 14.5, 
14.5, 14.5, 14.5, 14.5, 5, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 5, 5, 
5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 14.5, 14.5, 14.5, 14.5, 
14.5, 14.5, 14.5, 5, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23), lnf_t = c(-0.146448208, 
-0.294710745, -0.215722334, -0.351063681, -0.490825624, -1.001651248, 
-0.194844748, -0.063381609, -0.228461359, -0.82397007, -0.735022584, 
-0.542118918, -0.351063681, -0.142518929, -0.085360516, 0.590979547, 
0.799324877, 0.297631737, 0.391563556, 0.573885113, 0.356472237, 
-0.142518929, 0.084538521, 0.983174318, 0.852909123, 0.916088025, 
0.99455964, 0.790108222, 0.80845736, 0.857247525, -0.107833372, 
-0.241364764, -0.294710745, -0.228461359, -0.294710745, -0.190721031, 
-0.490825624, 0.490003629, -0.115437971, -0.542118918, -0.215722334, 
-0.267682072, -0.365662481, -0.096533816, 0.013311012, 0.607786665, 
0.412042088, 0.405262401, 0.218850859, 0.412042088, 0.432109651, 
0.585313809, 0.159761942, 1.176881197, 0.874415328, 0.99455964, 
1.34175584, 0.757164066, 1.031600912, 0.568121409, 0.337240875, 
-0.322490309, -0.322490309, -0.577837001, -0.254436846, -0.142518929, 
-0.215722334, -0.308504067, -0.115437971, -0.82397007, -0.596186139, 
-0.294710745, -0.756528789, -0.82397007, 0.065610511, 0.471075619, 
0.41877612, 0.672325186, 0.477424847, 0.490003629, 0.384643114, 
-0.410782916, -0.081663654, 0.723097511, 0.556493371, 0.496234179, 
0.451782416, 0.471075619, 0.377674444, 0.412042088, -0.375514777, 
-0.474296322, -0.693349888, -0.596186139, -0.474296322, -0.294710745, 
0.159761942, -0.474296322, -0.577837001, -0.410782916, -0.203143551, 
-0.166329578, -0.096533816, -0.336674944, 0.191148256, 0.464685821, 
0.526817602, 0.41877612, 0.2590169, 0.3274847, 0.177003749, -0.13082289, 
-0.013901552, 0.952164081, 0.891293366, 1.02795792, 0.92016135, 
1.084710737, 1.031600912, -0.052570693, -0.577837001, -0.336674944, 
-0.254436846, -0.308504067, -0.577837001, -0.490825624, -0.13470639, 
-0.778507696, -0.44203546, -0.351063681, -0.351063681, -0.559818495, 
-0.490825624, -0.524727175, -0.203143551, 0.398436436, 0.297631737, 
0.405262401, 0.218850859, 0.391563556, 0.168420005, -0.228461359, 
-0.285619773, 0.771416089, 0.544728529, 0.698033543, 0.550628251, 
0.502426149, 0.672325186, -0.281105093, -0.211511801, -0.351063681, 
-0.44203546, -1.088662625, 0.02, -0.44203546, -0.336674944, -0.653344553, 
-0.479775788, -0.490825624, -0.490825624, -0.410782916, -0.82397007, 
-0.614878272, -0.479775788, 0.438710335, 0.193953307, 0.185514438, 
-0.052570693, 0.106177696, 0.039802627, -0.142518929, -0.007028672, 
1.167402453, 1.070821625, 1.121940079, 1.27846099, 1.091583616, 
0.878661619, -0.395515444), sm_t = c(100, 93.04, 91.94, 90.84, 
88.83, 86.45, 100, 93.18, 92.71, 92.24, 92.47, 90.82, 91.53, 
80, 100, 93.18, 91.765, 90.35, 88, 85.88, 85.65, 59.53, 100, 
91.39, 89.24, 87.09, 86.68, 84.84, 84.63, 62.7, 100, 95.42, 95.23, 
95.04, 94.08, 90.84, 91.22, 78.24, 100, 89.32, 88.57, 87.82, 
85.68, 83.76, 100, 93.27, 91.98, 90.69, 89.31, 87.33, 85.54, 
72.08, 100, 90.58, 89.135, 87.69, 76.54, 73.65, 78.65, 48.85, 
100, 97.97, 96.02, 94.07, 90.68, 88.14, 82.37, 69.15, 100, 97.83, 
97.38, 96.93, 92.96, 90.25, 100, 97.83, 97.29, 96.75, 96.56, 
94.76, 95.48, 67.63, 100, 92.19, 90.04, 87.89, 84.34, 80.27, 
67.77, 42.97, 100, 94.18, 93, 91.82, 87.64, 85.09, 100, 97.82, 
96.395, 94.97, 91.62, 90.62, 85.93, 65.66, 100, 92, 89.265, 86.53, 
84.42, 81.89, 79.16, 58.74, 100, 96.96, 89.195, 81.43, 71.07, 
66.25, 60.71, 40.71, 100, 97.2, 96.62, 96.04, 92.31, 89.74, 100, 
97.34, 96.81, 96.28, 96.1, 95.39, 95.04, 81.74, 100, 98.3, 97.665, 
97.03, 95.54, 94.48, 94.48, 77.71, 100, 94.64, 89.88, 85.12, 
77.38, 70.04, 56.35, 42.86, 100, 96.03, 94.64, 93.25, 90.87, 
89.88, 88.29, 78.97, 100, 97.8, 97.105, 96.41, 93.81, 91.42, 
100, 98.73, 98.455, 98.18, 97.27, 95.82, 93.82, 73.82, 100, 97.34, 
94.105, 90.87, 86.5, 81.37, 61.41, 41.63)), .Names = c("temp", 
"lnf_t", "sm_t"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -180L
))
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read about making [reproducible examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). You are using data that we do not have access to, so no-one can reproduce this example to find the problem.  Also you could help by explaining more carefully what output is required and what is going wrong. You should edit this question once you have read the linked page.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I have updated my query with more details and included a dataset for reproducing the outputs following the link you provided. I hope that makes things clearer. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe not `persp(seq(x1), seq(x2), z, ...)` but `pmat <- persp(seq(x1), seq(x2), z, ...)`.

Comment: Thanks, that almost worked! only now I have a bunch of points in space, not on my surface. I will try adjust it and revise my question if that fails :)